# How to scrape web content and then count frequencies of words in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, text-mining, tm

This is my code:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url.link <- 'http://www.jamesaltucher.com/sitemap.xml'
blog <- getURL(url.link)
blog          <- htmlParse(blog, encoding = "UTF-8")
titles  <- xpathSApply (blog ,"//loc",xmlValue)             ## titles

traverse_each_page <- function(x){
  tmp <- htmlParse(x)
  xpathApply(tmp, '//div[@id="mainContent"]')
}
pages <- lapply(titles[2:3], traverse_each_page)
```

Here is the pseudocode:

1. Take a xml document: `http://www.jamesaltucher.com/sitemap.xml`
2. Go to each link
3. Parse the html content of each link
4. Extract the text inside `div id="mainContent"`
5. Count the frequencies of each word that appears for all the articles, case-insensitive.

**I have managed to complete steps 1-4. I need some help with no. 5.**

Basically if the word "the" appears twice in article 1 and five times in article 2. I want to know that "the" appears a total of seven times in 2 articles.

**Also, I do not know how to view the contents I have extracted into `pages`. I want to learn how to view the contents which will make it easier for me to debug.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go, start to finish. I changed your code for web-scraping so it gets less non-text stuff and then down the bottom is the word counts.

Here's your code for downloading the URLs...

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url.link <- 'http://www.jamesaltucher.com/sitemap.xml'
blog <- getURL(url.link)
blog          <- htmlParse(blog, encoding = "UTF-8")
titles  <- xpathSApply (blog ,"//loc",xmlValue)             ## titles
```

I've changed your function to extract the text from each page...

```
traverse_each_page <- function(x){
  tmp <- htmlParse(getURI(x))
  xpathSApply(tmp, '//div[@id="mainContent"]', xmlValue)
}
pages <- sapply(titles[2:3], traverse_each_page)
```

Let's remove newline and other non-text characters...

```
nont <- c("\n", "\t", "\r")
pages <- gsub(paste(nont,collapse="|"), " ", pages)
```

Regarding your second question, to inspect the contents in `pages`, just type it at the console:

```
pages
```

Now let's do your step 5 'Count the frequencies of each word that appears for all the articles, case-insensitive.'

```
require(tm)
# convert list into corpus 
mycorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(pages))
# prepare to remove stopwords, ie. common words like 'the'
skipWords <- function(x) removeWords(x, stopwords("english"))
# prepare to remove other bits we usually don't care about
funcs <- list(tolower, removePunctuation, removeNumbers, stripWhitespace, skipWords)
# do it
a <- tm_map(mycorpus, FUN = tm_reduce, tmFuns = funcs)
# make document term matrix
mydtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(a, control = list(wordLengths = c(3,10)))
```

Here's where you see the count of each word per document

```
inspect(mydtm)
# you can assign it to a data frame for more convenient viewing
my_df <- inspect(mydtm)
my_df
```

Here's how you count the total frequencies of each word that appears for all the articles, case-insensitive...

```
apply(mydtm, 2, sum)
```

Does that answer your question? I guess that you're probably really only interested in the most frequent words (as @buruzaemon's answer details), or a certain sub-set of words, but that's another question...

Comment: This is a detailed answer. I am still figuring it out line by line. Do give me some time to confirm this. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me. I am now left with exporting the result set out to an excel file http://stackoverflow.com/q/20159691/80353

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at the R `tm` package. Vignette is [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf). `tm` has everything you need to deal with corpora and building term-document matrices.

In principle, this would entail:

1. Creating a `Corpus` from your data, possibly discarding punctuation, numbers, stopwords
2. Create a `TermDocumentMatrix` from your `Corpus` or corpora, depending on what you are doing
3. Use `as.matrix` on your `TermDocumentMatrix`, and do `rowSums` on your raw matrix to obtain word counts

Here is a brief code snippet as example:

```
library(tm)

ctrl <- list(stopwords=T,
             removePunctuation=T,
             removeNumbers=T)

# assuming your data is in some dataframe already...
corpus1 <- Corpus(DataframeSource(...))    
corpus2 <- Corpus(DataframeSource(...))

corp.all <- c(corpus1, corpus2)

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp.all, ctrl)
tdm.m <- as.matrix(tdm)

counts <- rowSums(tdm.m)

my.model <- data.frame(cbind(names(counts), as.numeric(counts)),
                       stringsAsFactors=F)

names(my.model) <- c('term', 'frequency')

my.model$frequency <- as.numeric(my.model$frequency)

head(my.model[with(my.model, order(-frequency)),], 20)
```

I think that you might want to discard [stop words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) like "the", since they tend to be very frequent and thus not very important. More detailed information on text mining in general can be found from this [CrossValidated question thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12466/examples-of-text-mining-with-r-tm-package).

Comment: Thanks for providing information on discarding stop words. In fact, I have never heard of the term `stop words` before. Please give me some time to try out your answer. Thank you!~

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me. I am now left with exporting the result set out to an excel file stackoverflow.com/q/20159691/80353

Comment: No problem, @KimStacks, hope you were able to complete your task.