# How do I export a double matrix to an excel or csv?

Tags: r, excel, csv, export

I asked [a question about using R to perform some web scraping for some data analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19851655/80353).

Now I have the data I want. It is in a double matrix.

[image]

I am using . How do I export that double matrix to use in Excel?

**EDIT:**

I also have mydtm as a DocumentTermMatrix. Would that one be easier to extract?

**EDIT:**
The code is included here : https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/7613396

Comment: there is a lot of information contained within an object of class dgeMatrix (i.e. a double matrix) and it isn't entirely clear how this would translate into a spreadsheet or csv. what do you want the export to look like?

Comment: @joemienko basically the R file is looking for frequency of keywords in these articles. So I was hoping to be able to extract at least the keywords with non-zero frequency and their frequencies. In the screenshot you can see that the word ability appears once in books and why-twitter articles. That refers to the frequency

Comment: Do you *really* prefer graphing in Excel to R?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Well I am more familiar with Excel. Sorry for being a newbie. I of course will be happy with a solution that shows me how to do that in R as well.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have got the data in the R studio, you can simply use the `write.csv` command for writing into csv format:

```
write.csv(my_df, "your_file_name.csv", row.names=T)
```

This will create a file `your_file_name.csv` with the data of `my_df` in your current working directory.

#### EDIT:

As this won't be working for a double matrix, you could form a new character matrix in the following way and then use `write.csv`:

```
my_df_new <- matrix(0, 9, 1715)
my_df_new[,2:1715] <- my_df[,2:1715]
my_df_new[,1] <- as.character(my_df[,1])
write.csv(my_df_new, "your_file_name.csv", row.names=T)
```

Please try this.

Comment: write.csv (or any of the write wrappers for cat) do not know how to handle a double matrix. I think he'll need to extract a desired subset of the slots and export the subset.

Comment: yeah right, I tried to simulate a similar matrix, but apparently it got converted to character matrix due to the url in the first column and I didn't check it

Comment: @joemienko I guess the approach I posted in the edit will convert the double matrix to a character matrix

Comment: @KimStacks can you please tell what `class(my_df[1,1])` gives and also the output of `as.character(my_df[1,1:2])`

Comment: @KimStacks I have run the code you shared on [github](https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/7613396) without any changes and instead of the 4 lines of code I have given in my answer, I used this one at last `write.csv(my_df, "your_file_name.csv", row.names=T)`. A csv file was generated in my working directory. You can download that file from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/98940366/your_file_name.csv). So, I would like to say that there is no fault in the code as I see and am able to generate csv file with the above command.